# Difference between a querystring and a fragment?

Tags: jquery, jquery-bbq

When using jQuery BBQ they are using the words "querystring" and "fragment".

What is the difference btween the two?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the definition of a URL (see e.g. [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html)):

> Fragment URLs
>
> The URL specification en vigeur at the
>   writing of this document ([RFC1738])
>   offers a mechanism to refer to a
>   resource, but not to a location within
>   a resource. The Web community has
>   adopted a convention called "fragment
>   URLs" to refer to anchors within an
>   HTML document. A fragment URL ends
>   with "#" followed by an anchor
>   identifier. For instance, here is a
>   fragment URL pointing to an anchor
>   named section_2:
>
> http://somesite.com/html/top.html#section_2

The `#section_2` part is also called "the fragment".  Its interpretation is up to the user agent (AKA client AKA browser), though the universal convention is that it's the anchor of an `<a>` tag to which the browser is asked to position itself.

The Query String, as explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), is the part of the URL that's passed to the server-side program -- normally after a `?` and up to but excluding the `#` if any.  So, in:

```
http://server/path/program?query_string#thefrag
```

the query string would be `query_string` and the fragment would be `thefrag`.